# Can't Publish to Wordpress from Org2Blog in Emacs

Tags: wordpress, emacs, org-mode

I am using emacs and the org2blog mode plugin to post articles to my Wordpress blog. A few months ago, I used this method exclusively and it worked. But I took a four month break from blogging.

Anyway, now when I try to post, I get the following:

```
xml-rpc-request: Why? url-http-response-status is nil
```

I don't understand why this won't work. Here's the relevant lines from my .emacs file:

```
(setq org2blog/wp-blog-alist
      '(("Thinking and Believing"
     :url "http://micahcobb.com/blog/xmlrpc.php"
     :username "cobbmic")))
```

Anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: And yes, I know that there's a similar question on SO that was supposedly answered, but the solution (update Org-Mode) doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably a network error. Have you tried it recently? If it still happens, I would instrument `xml-rpc-method-call` for edebug and step through it with the debugger.

Or you might try setting `xml-rpc-debug` to something > 1 and see if you get any hints.

Also there is a comment in xml-rpc.el that might be relevant, although I have no idea what the keep-alive bug is:

```
(when (not (numberp url-http-response-status))
  ;; this error may occur when keep-alive bug
  ;; of url-http.el is not cleared.
  (error "Why? url-http-response-status is %s"
                            url-http-response-status))
```

If all else fails, I would open an issue in the org2blog Github repo.